# Creating polygons of specific slope percentage from a slope raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, slope

I am trying to extract all areas where the slope is greater than 20% and then turn those areas into a polygon.

I'm using QGIS 3.0.2.

Comment: Could you describe how your slope raster have the value? Does the unit already set to percentage? Or, in other units (e.g. degrees)? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you created slope percent image from the DEM data and I will start from there. You can extract the slope percent that are greater than 20% using the following workflow:

- Load the slope percent data into QGIS canvas

[image]

- Use Raster calculator to extract the slope values that are greater than 20% and save the output raster file:

  ```
  "SlopePercent@1" > 20
  ```

[image]

- The output data will contain raster values of 0 and 1. The value of 0 represents the slope values of less than and 20% and the value of 1 represents the slope values of greater than 20%

[image]

- Use Polygonize tool from Processing toolbox -> GDAL -> Raster conversion -> Polygonize (Raster to Vector), and Select the result from the previous step as input file

[image]

- The output polygon shapefile will contain both 0 and 1 in the attribute table

[image]

- Use Select features using an expression [image] from the attribute table to select all the 1 values using the following formula:

  ```
  "DN" = 1
  ```

[image]

- Right-click the polygon shapefile and check `Save only selected features`:

[image]

Here is the final result:

[image]